# On properties of thick sets.

Tags: set-theory

I am studying about thick sets and their properties. In various places, its written that a thick set contains arbitrary large intervals. Also, I came across this property in one lecture notes. It said that if a subset A of $\mathbb{N}$ is thick then the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}:kn \in A\}$ is also thick for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Its mentioned there that it is a fact. I do not follow this step nor I could find this statement anywhere else.
It would be great if someone could help me with the proof for this statement: If a subset A of $\mathbb{N}$ is thick then the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}:kn \in A\}$ is also thick for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited it. @K.Jiang

Comment: The set theory tag is not for "questions about sets". I don't think this tag is suitable, and I have no better suggestion. Mainly since I've never heard that term before and I can't place it in context of a research subject.

Comment: "In various places", "it is mentioned there", "one lecture notes"… Why not tell us *what* places, where is *there*, *what* lecture notes?

Comment: By the way, you could also tell us what a thick set is…

Comment: All I know about thick sets is that it is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that contains arbitrarily large intervals. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez.

Answer (score 0):

An interval of $A$ with length $km$ yields an interval of $B_k=\{n \mid kn \in A \}$ of length $m$.  Since $A$ has arbitrarily long intervals, so does $B_k$.